# explain in detail TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy for log4j2 v2.3

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

Can someone demystify TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy for log4j2 v2.3 and its arguments ?

1. what do you mean by most specific time unit ?
2. is the rollover strategy applicable for only time based trigger or it will be applicable for any triggering policy.

The document says 
"

> The TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy causes a rollover once the date/time
>   pattern no longer applies to the active file. This policy accepts an
>   increment attribute which indicates how frequently the rollover should
>   occur based on the time pattern and a modulate boolean attribute.
>
> TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy Parameters
>
> Parameter Name   Type    Description
>
> interval integer How often a rollover should occur based on the most
>   specific time unit in the date pattern. For example, with a date
>   pattern with hours as the most specific item and and increment of 4
>   rollovers would occur every 4 hours. The default value is 1.
>
> modulate boolean Indicates whether the interval should be adjusted to
>   cause the next rollover to occur on the interval boundary. For
>   example, if the item is hours, the current hour is 3 am and the
>   interval is 4 then then the first rollover will occur at 4 am and then
>   next ones will occur at 8 am, noon, 4pm, etc.
>
> "

Comment: "what do you mean by most specific time unit ?" - Very confusing choice of words, yes. Basically it means "the smallest". So Hour is more "specific" than Day , Minute is more specific than Hour ...

Comment: :-) thank you @Fildor .That simplifies !!